# Efficient regex with lists

Tags: python, regex, performance

I have a list of strings coming from `os.listdir()` that looks like the following:

```
['foo',
 'bar'
 'backup_20180406'
 ...]
```

out of those entries, I wanna get the ones that match the *"backup_YYYYMMDD"* pattern. The regex for that, with named groups, would be

```
regex = r"BACKUP_(?P<date>\d+)"
```

I am trying to create a list that contains the **date only** from the above (aka the `.group('date')`), but I cannot find a way to do it without parsing the strings twice..

```
res = [re.search(regex, x).group('date') for x in filter(r.match, os.listdir(folder))]
```

I am sure that I am missing something really obvious and concise here, so is there a better way?

Comment: Maybe `re.findall(r"(?i)BACKUP_(\d+)", " ".join(os.listdir(folder)))` will do?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thought about it too but I dislike the `join` bit.. Then again, using a weird character as separator and adjusting the reg-ex should make it very stable

Comment: You're gonna need some kind of temporary variable; there's no way around it. List comprehensions aren't suited for this kind of thing.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, remember to select an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually do:

```
regex = re.compile(r"BACKUP_(?P<date>\d+)")
a = ['foo', "BACKUP_20180406", 'xxx']
matches = [regex.match(x) for x in a]
valid = [x.group('date') for x in matches if x]
```

Or just

```
valid = [x.group('date') for x in (regex.match(y) for y in a) if x]
```

Also notice that `regex.match` is *much faster* than `regex.search` when applicable - i.e. when you search from the beginning of the line.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis How so? Yours does the regex matching twice; this one doesn't.

Comment: @Aran-Fey You are right, I guess it's one of these confused-Mondays. I actually like this answer now/

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Pandas solution, using `extract()`:

```
import pandas as pd

strings = ['foo', 'bar', 'backup_20180406']
regex = r"backup_(?P<date>\d+)"

pd.Series(strings).str.extract(regex).dropna()

2    20180406
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Comment: Interesting.. +1, though I would prefer not importing anything else.

Comment: It seems like this solution is not very fast (see my answer)

Answer (score -1):

Regex are rarely the most efficient tools if you are testing a simple pattern.
Just using startswith makes it twice as fast.

```
from timeit import timeit
import re

size = 10000
data = ['foo','bar','backup_20180406'] * size

def find_dates(data):
    prefix = 'backup_'
    prefix_size = len(prefix)
    return [name[prefix_size:] for name in data if name.startswith(prefix)]

def find_dates_testing_numbers(data):
    prefix = 'backup_'
    prefix_size = len(prefix)
    for name in data:
        if name.startswith(prefix):
            try:
                yield int(name[prefix_size:])
            except ValueError:
                pass

def find_dates_regex(data):
    regex = re.compile(r"backup_(?P<date>\d+)")
    return [x.group('date') for x in (regex.match(y) for y in data) if x]

def find_dates_pd(data):
    import pandas as pd
    regex = r"backup_(?P<date>\d+)"
    return pd.Series(data).str.extract(regex).dropna()

result = find_dates(data)
print(timeit('find_dates(data)', globals=globals(), number=1000))
# 4.02514289499959 seconds

print(timeit('list(find_dates_testing_numbers(data))', globals=globals(), number=1000))
# 6.0529899510002 seconds

print(timeit('find_dates_regex(data)', globals=globals(), number=1000))
# 8.772153561999403 seconds

print(timeit('find_dates_pd(data)', globals=globals(), number=1000))
# 19.018224569999802
```

Comment: The solution with string operations may be the fastest, but it doesn't check if the file name ends with a date. It'll pick up things like `backup_foo` as well.

Comment: You are right. Edited. Still faster than regex. Of course regex are very useful and powerful, but they are slower when the pattern tested is very simple.

Comment: 100% agree with your comment about avoiding regex if possible. But this is not an answer to the original question

Comment: I don't say you must avoid regex. I say that you must choose the best tool depending on your needs.